# Unable to access vline.Message object with postMessage()

Tags: javascript, vline

While implementing the vLine API, I came up with a problem. When using the `postMessage()` method of the `vline.Channel` class, the message was successfully received by the target user, but the the success callback of `vline.Promise` object did not return a valid `vline.Message` object. At least I don't have acess to some of the `vline.Message` methods, like `getChannel()` or `getCreationTime()`.

**Code:**

```
$channel.postMessage(textMessage)
    .done(function (message) {
        console.log("Message sending successfull || Message sent to " + message.getChannel().getDisplayName() + " at " + message.getCreationTime());
    },
    this)
    .fail(function (err) {
        console.log("Message sending failed || Error Type: " + err.type + " || Error Message: " + err.message);
    },
    this);
```

**Result (console log):**

```
Message sending failed || Error Type: undefined || Error Message: Object #<Object> has no method 'getChannel'
```

Is this result of a API change that has not been yet referenced on the vLine Developer site or is there an error on the code?

Comment: It looks like a bug on our side where we're not returning a fully-formed `vline.Message` object. I'll post an update when this is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug on our end; sorry about that. It should now be fixed.